# How can I add a Maven dependency to a project that needs to be checked out via svn?

Tags: svn, maven, maven-scm

I want to distribute my project that has a dependency to [another project](https://code.google.com/p/google-gimlet/) hosted on Google code that is only available in source code (there is no compiled jar version available.)

I am aware of the [Maven SCM plugin](http://maven.apache.org/scm/maven-scm-plugin/) but have never used it.  I'd like to know how I can create and configure a Maven project to check the code out via svn and register it as a required project dependency.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create an issue for gimlet to published to Maven central and help them do it. That would be the best way for everybody. It is already being built with Maven so it should not be too hard to do. Look at the repository plugin for help with the upload.

Comment: I had [already done so](https://code.google.com/p/google-gimlet/issues/detail?id=1).  :)

Answer (score 3):

Build the other project yourself and deploy it, if you have hosting (maybe use a repo manager such as Nexus). Change the version number to reflect that it's not 'official'. Then (per the other answer) when they deploy to Maven Central, you can just change the version in your own project pom.